# При попытке сделать .exe файл выдает ошибку cannot find existing pyqt5 plugin directories

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Хочу с помощью pyinstaller переделать свой код в exe файл, но выдает ошибку cannot find existing pyqt5 plugin directories

```
:\Program Files\Crestiki\Project>pyinstaller test.py
```

```
79 INFO: Python: 3.7.7
80 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
80 INFO: wrote C:\Program Files\Crestiki\Project\test.spec
82 INFO: UPX is not available.
84 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Program Files\\Crestiki\\Project', 'C:\\Program Files\\Crestiki\\Project']
127 INFO: checking Analysis
127 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
127 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
129 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
140 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2672 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\ильсаф\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
2673 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\ильсаф\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib'
4985 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5098 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5100 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
5167 INFO: Analyzing C:\Program Files\Crestiki\Project\test.py
5209 INFO: Processing module hooks...
5209 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\ильсаф\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5211 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\ильсаф\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5297 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'c:\\users\\ильсаф\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5503 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
5503 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'c:\\users\\ильсаф\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5575 WARNING: Unable to find Qt5 translations C:/users/èëüñàô/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/translations\qtbase_*.qm. These translations were not packaged.
5575 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'c:\\users\\ильсаф\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Ильсаф\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 711, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 658, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Crestiki\Project\test.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 236, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 413, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 359, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 420, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 387, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 588, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py", line 13, in <module>
    hiddenimports, binaries, datas = add_qt5_dependencies(__file__)
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 538, in add_qt5_dependencies
    more_binaries = qt_plugins_binaries(plugin, namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 146, in qt_plugins_binaries
    pdir = qt_plugins_dir(namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\ильсаф\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 131, in qt_plugins_dir
    """.format(namespace, ", ".join(paths)))
Exception:
            Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
            Paths checked: C:/users/èëüñàô/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins``
```

Comment: Попробуйте для начала почитать посты https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt5%5D+cannot+find+existing+pyqt5+plugin+directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал Вам переставить питон в папку с коротким путем c:\python37 например. И обязательно без кириллицы в пути к файлам.

Comment: Для этого мне нужно питн переустанавливать или могу просто папку перенести?

Comment: нет. переустанавливайте питон и все библиотеки. И обязательно питон ставьте с python.org. Не с microsoft store

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все проблемы были из-за кирилицы.